# [GUI] [Err] [MeshManager.cc:131] Invalid mesh filename extension

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm getting the following errors using a [simple sdf file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gazebosim/gazebo-classic/gazebo9/worlds/animated_box.world) that I get from the tutorial of animating a box:

```
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [GUI] [Err] [MeshManager.cc:131] Invalid mesh filename extension[tutorial/worlds/__default__]
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [GUI] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:1027] Actor skin mesh [tutorial/worlds/__default__] not found.
```

I'm using Gazebo garden on ubuntu 22.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28887/%5Bgui%5D-%5Berr%5D-%5Bmeshmanager.cc:131%5D-invalid-mesh-filename-extension/) by [jaouadros](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/149266/jaouadros/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2023-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It seems not possible to use collada object in modern gazebo, unless it has a mesh with skeletal animation. instead you can use [trajectory follower](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/gz-sim7/examples/worlds/trajectory_follower.sdf).

---

Originally posted by [jaouadros](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/149266/jaouadros/) with karma: 1 on 2023-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0